# Chosen Select, Searching by a property and show labels

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using Chosen Select with chosenAjax

My case is the next... I have this data

```
[{name: "Name to show", property: "Using this field by search", id: 1},
 {name: "Name to show", property: "Using this field by search", id: 2} ]
```

How can I search by a field, and showing other text in the html?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do this

```
$('.chosen-ajax').ajaxChosen({
    type: "GET",
    url: "my_path",
    dataType: 'json'
  }, function(data){
     var result = [];    
     for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var value = data[i];
      result.push({"value" : value.id, "search_text" : value.property  ,text: value.name})
     }
     return result;
   }
)
```

Important: 
   You must add "search_text"